# vim - running dd range command using command line

Tags: vim, dd

For deleting a range of lines, I know we can use :3,15d and it works. But if we try to run the same command using normal command (:3,15 normal dd), it behaves erratic and deletes some random blocks/lines in 3,15 range. Could anyone explain if this is a bug?

Comment: Please can you better explain your problem? Maybe you can give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:norm` iterates over lines with specific addresses, not over lines with specific marks.

Suppose you have this file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

And you execute `:2,4norm! dd`.
You probably expect getting this file:

```
line 1
line 5
line 6
```

But in reality, you'll get this file:

```
line 1
line 3
line 5
```

First, `:norm` executes the `dd` command on the line whose address is `2`; at that point, the file contains:

```
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

Then, `:norm` executes the `dd` command on the line whose address is `3`. But since `:norm` has removed a line in the previous step, all the addresses of the lines below the deleted line have decreased by 1.
So the line of address `3` is not the one containing the text `line 3` anymore, but the one containing the text `line 4`; and `:norm` deletes the latter; at that point, the file contains:

```
line 1
line 3
line 5
line 6
```

Finally, `:norm` executes the `dd` command on the line whose address is `4`. But again, since `:norm` has removed 2 lines in the previous steps, all the addresses of the subsequent lines have decreased by 2; and the line of address `4` is not the one containing the text `line 4` anymore, but the one containing the text `line 6`; `:norm` deletes the latter and the file finally contains:

```
line 1
line 3
line 5
```

---

If for some reason, you really want to use `:norm! dd`, combine it with `:g` which contrary to `:norm` does mark the lines on which it operates before executing its command argument:

```
:3,15g/^/norm! dd
```

Or try to reverse the order of the deletions:

```
:call map(reverse(range(3, 15)), {_,v -> execute(v.'norm! dd')})
```

---

Always append a bang to `:norm`, unless you really want your custom mappings to be taken into account.

---

If your file is folded, make sure folding is temporarily disabled; execute `:setl nofen` before the deletions, then `:setl fen` afterward.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.